# What are the ways to select distinct count in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-enterprise-graph

I need to select distinct count in table in cassandra.

As I understand direct distinct count is not supported in cassandra not even nested queries like rdbms.

```
select count(*) from (select distinct key_part_one from stackoverflow_composite) as count;
```

> SyntaxException: line 1:21 no viable alternative at input '(' (select count(*) from [(]...)

What are the ways to get it. whether I can get directly from cassandra or any addon tools/languages need to be used?

below is my create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE nishant_ana.ais_profile_table (
    profile_key text,
    profile_id text,
    last_update_day date,
    last_transaction_timestamp timestamp,
    last_update_insertion_timestamp timeuuid,
    profile_data blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((profile_key, profile_id), last_update_day)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (last_update_day DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

I have just started using cassandra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cassandra you can only do the `select distinct partition_key from ...`.

If you need something like this, you can use Spark + [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/doc) - it will work, but don't expect really real-time answers, as it needs to read necessary data from all nodes, and then calculate answer.